# PHPStorm / WebStorm - Open File in Browser on LocalHost After Setting Up Deployment Endpoint

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I have a project in PHPStorm which I've set up a deployment location on an Amazon EC2 server.  When I right click on a HTML file now, I get the following option:

[image]

"amazon" is the name of the deployment location I've configured.

Before I added a deployment location, the same option above used to open my file on my localhost.

Is there a way to do the same now that I've added a deployment location?  I would like to have a short-cut that allows me to look at my files in real-time without having to upload them onto my deployment machine first.

Comment: This option works with Default deployment server only (AFAIK). If you **unmark** your deployment entry as being Default .. the IDE will use built-in web server again. Of course, you can try and define another deployment entry where local/built-in/whatever server will be used and see if you will get multiple options for this action -- but I do not think it is working like that (only with Default, I believe).

Comment: @LazyOne I think I might have deleted my Default deployment config.  Is there a way to get it back?

Comment: You mean you have deleted your "amazon" entry? No .. unless you have have backups of your `.idea` subfolder (project settings) and (more importantly) the PhpStorm/WebStorm global folder (`~/.WebIdeXX` kind of folders) where IDE-wide configs are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking off the default marker from the deployment profile which allowed me to run a local server using the shortcut mentioned above and still sync with the remote server using my normal keyboard binding.

[image]